# Gatsby flicker (FOUC) on page load and page refresh

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby, tailwind-css, postcss

We are facing a flicker issue/FOUC with our website. Have researched a lot of threads on the internet, github issues, stackoverflow but nothing has helped yet.
The site can be viewed here - https://crio-sandbox.netlify.app/

At the moment, we are running Gatsby v2.32.10 but the same issue persists on v3 as well. We use TailwindCSS along with SCSS.
The root cause still remains unknown. Any help would be appreciated :)

P.S: I'd be happy to share any other info if needed.

Imports in gatsby-browser.js - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc0HQ.png

Comment: Can you provide how are you importing the global styles?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I am importing all my styles in gatsby-browser.js file.
It's a mix of CSS and SCSS.
Font's are also imported using font-source in the same file.

Comment: Can you provide it? It's extremely difficult to help without code

Comment: Sure, here you go - https://i.imgur.com/7ZYTVYr.png

Comment: Okay, so I was experimenting random stuff, and for some reason I commented out few 3rd party analytics packages such as Google Analytics, Tag Manager from the gatsby-config.js file and the flicker vanished.Also, I tried turning on my adblocker and loading the site, and the flicker came back. Could this mean something?

Comment: Depending on how are they inserted. If they block the rendering, could be but it's difficult to see with 0 code...

Comment: @Ferran--I am having the same issue as well, my code can be found here: https://github.com/cjones26/niggling-aspirations-blog.